# How to use printf() without any libraries in C?

Tags: c, printf, teensy, implicit-declaration

I am programming a Teensy micro-controller as a part of a C course and am trying to work out the value of one of my integer variables. I have an integer variable called **Contrast**, which is initialised to the value of a constant defined as a hexadecimal number at the beginning of the .c file:

```
#define LCD_DEFAULT_CONTRAST    0x3F 
int Contrast = LCD_DEFAULT_CONTRAST;
```

I am trying to investigate how this **Contrast** value is stored and displayed, if it shows up as **63** or **0x3F**, and if they are interchangeable. I tried to use:

```
printf("%d", Contrast);
```

to print out the **Contrast** value to the terminal and I got the error **implicit declaration of function `'printf'`**. I thought `printf()` was part of the built-in C library, so I am confused why this is not working.

Can anyone please tell me how I print the value of this variable to the screen?

Comment: so you **did** include `stdio.h`?

Comment: btw, this value is stored as a number, in **binary** ... for printing, you convert it to a string, and `%d` will result in a **decimal** number in that string, while `%x`, which is for **unsigned** numbers, results in a **hexadecimal** number This has nothing to do with how it is stored.

Comment: What do you mean by "without any libraries"? Why don't you want them? How does your micro-controller display anything? Monitor? Segment display? Pixel display? Morse-beeper?

Comment: A cross-compiler for a microcontroller might need to have `printf` specifically enabled, because the function has a lot of code which may be dead weight on the memory available.

Comment: "*how this Contrast value is stored and displayed, if it shows up as 63 or 0x3F*" - It's stored as a number. It's displayed however your code decides to display it.

Answer (score 4):

The implicit declaration error just means your compiler proper doesn't have a declaration for `printf`. Unless you're also getting a linker error, the linker (linking usually follows compilation, unless you pass `-c` to disable it) is probably slapping the standard lib right on, in which case you can simply solve your warning by including `stdio.h` or less preferably by declaring `int printf(char const*, ...);`.

If you trully don't have the standard lib, you'll need to convert the integer to a string manually with something like:

```
int n = 42;
char buf[20];
char *end = buf+(sizeof(buf)-1), *p = end;
*p--=0;
if(n==0) *p=='0';
else{
    while(n){
        printf("%d\n", n%10);
        *p--=n%10+'0'; 
        n/=10;
    }
    p++;
}
```

and then pass it to your system's raw IO routine for which you'll need to have set up the system-entering assembly.

If you don't have a system, it'd be even more technical, and you probably wouldn't be asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

`printf()` is declared in standard library header `<stdio.h>`.

You have to `#include <stdio.h>` to use `printf()`. It is a library call, much like all other library calls in C..

Comment: `#include` in C. You are thinking of another language. (Technically, `printf` is **declared** in stdio.h.)

Comment: Edited. How can you even print to stdout without using any libraries. I checked souirce of stdio.h and it is full of #define and functions beginning with two underscores.

Comment: "How can you even print to stdout without using any libraries" --> `<stdio.h>` and the _standard library_ are different things.  It is possible to use one and not the other - and cause this type of trouble.